# How to configure spring boot integration tests with random coordinates of external mocks?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, testing, spring-test

I have a spring boot application that sends requests to external services. url and port of those services are configured using standard spring boot way - configuration properties. During integration tests i want to start my external mocks (e.g. test-container) using random free port, provide this port to spring-boot config and start the spring boot app.

but any `@SpringBootTest` requires config provided in annotation. that must be static. there is no way to provide a port this way. i need something like:

```
class IntegrationTest {

  static int port;

  @BeforeAll
  static void initialize_external_mocks() {
     port = start_docker_and_get_its_port()
  }

  @Test
  void should_call_external_service() {

     start_my_spring_boot_app_with_port(port); // how to do this?

     restTemplate.get("/my-spring-boot-app/request");

     assert_my_docker_received_a_call_from_my_app();
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you have a look at [`DynamicPropertySource`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/context/DynamicPropertySource.html) ?

Comment: yep, just found that. should solve my problem